# Xdebug MacOS Big Sur M1(ARM)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

Honestly, I've tried everything trying to get this working. I am a bit new to MacOS but I am starting to get the hang of it.

I've installed Xdebug on my mac with XAMPP and VSCode as editor. It's still just not working and I think it is not connecting.

php.ini

```ini
[XDebug]
zend_extension = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp"
```

VSCode launch.json:

```
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003
```

And yes, my file is at that exact location.
If anyone has any glues on what's going on, I'll be glad to know.

**UPDATE**
So I've check my error logs and I've gotten this problem:

> [12-Oct-2021 07:00:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'xdebug' (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug, 9): image not found), /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture)) in Unknown on line 0

On the website it says that xdebug is only supported with homebrew. But installing php with homebrew is not the same thing as with XAMPP. I am starting to think that I just cannot use XAMPP and XDebug together but have to use the integrated apache.

XDebug Wizard:

> Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions.
> On your Mac, we only support installations with 'homebrew', and brew install php && brew install autoconf should pull in the right packages."

When I look up the php version in the terminal it gets the version in homebrew, so I deleted it. It may be that when I used ./configure it took the PATH to homebrew. That is probably why the image is not correct.

Whatever the problem may be, I cannot find any kind of solution and have tried many things

Comment: Which version of Xdebug is loaded? To find out make a script with `<?php xdebug_info(); ?>` in it and show what it says.

Comment: @Myrras Just what Derick said -- What is your Xdebug version? You are using Xdebug v2 params. But current Xdebug version v3 now uses different parameter names and v2 params do nothing on v3. https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide P.S. I suggest you post `xdebug_info()` output (or the whole Xdebug section from `phpinfo()`) -- it will show your current/live config. I also suggest you enable Xdebug log -- it will tell where it tries to connect (if it tries at all, of course) and what the response is. BTW: 1) https://learnxdebug.com/ 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: xdebug_info() is not working @Derick It doesn't show up at phpinfo either. So I think it isn't getting loaded

Comment: Make sure you're updating the right `php.ini` then - phpinfo() will tell you which one to update, and it can be different for CLI and or Webserver requests.

Comment: I looked for the same thing and noticed when I used php -m that it took a different php.ini

Comment: This is my php -m output: https://justpaste.it/5q969

Comment: Found problem: Failed loading /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days trying to fix this I finally got it.
What you need to do is the following:

Step 1:
Check PATH in Terminal

```
which php
```

Step 2:
If this is not your current http server like XAMPP or MAMP please correct it by making a ./bash_profile
MAMP Example: https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693
XAMPP Example: https://gist.github.com/djandyr/c04950a1375e96814316

Step 3:
Check php version again (repeat step 1).
If this is the version of your http server then it's OK.

Step 4:
Type in terminal

```
php -v
```

Step 5:
If your xDebug cannot be loaded it will tell you why now. (or in the error logs).
As I've said I've got a M1 Macbook and I think xDebug doesn't support M1.

Step 6:
To install xDebug
terminal:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Step 7:
Now restart all and try your phpinfo.

Happy debugging!

Comment: "Step 6: Because xDebug doesn't support M1" — Xdebug supports M1 just fine. It depends on what architecture PHP is compiled as, and Xdebug needs to match that architecture.

Comment: Ah, so I just installed the wrong package and not that xDebug doesn't support ARM. I hope my guide is still helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in this message:

> mach-o, but wrong architecture

On M1, your PHP can either be compiled for the x86_64 or arm64 architectures. The `pecl` tool can't guess which one it is, so if your PHP is compiled with say x86_64 and the default compiler setting is arm64, then you'll get the above warning.

This means, that sometimes you have to run PECL with:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

The `arch -x86_64` part will set up the environment to compile Xdebug as x86_64 binary.

You can check what the architecture for your PHP is, by using:

```
file /full/path/to/php
```